# Multiple plots are not rendered as described by layout.show

Tags: r, plot, r-raster

Using the `raster` package and its `plot` function, I want to arrange six plots of `Raster*` objects in 2 rows and 3 columns, by columns. Therefore I set up my layout like this:

```r
layout(mat=matrix(1:6, nrow=2, ncol=3), heights=c(1,1), widths=c(2,1,1))
```

Calling `layout.show(6)` results in this preview, which is exactly what I want:

[image]

However, after the first plot being placed where the 1 is (as expected), the second plot is placed where the 3 is (not as expected). **Why's that?**

When I then call `layout.show(6)` again, I get this, which is NOT what I want:

[image]

Interestingly, using `par(mfcol=c(2,3))` instead of `layout` *also* placed the plots by row (i.e. behaved like `mfrow`).

(I'm aware I could just rearrange the order of `plot` calls, but I want to know why this doesn't work as I expect it to.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this with `plot(Raster*)` as that sets the layout itself; thus overwriting your settings. Instead of `plot(x)` you could use `image(x)`, but then you do not get a legend.

Perhaps the best approach is to use the `terra` package instead (`terra` is the replacement for `raster`). Also note argument "clip".

```
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
layout(mat=matrix(1:6, nrow=2, ncol=3), heights=c(1,1), widths=c(2,1,1))
plot(r)
plot(r, clip=FALSE)
plot(r)
plot(r, clip=FALSE)
plot(r)
plot(r, clip=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your quick reply and sorry about the missing example. What do you mean with "sets the layout itself"? That it too calls `layout` and thus overwrites my previous settings?
I will look into `image` as I don't necessarily need a legend anyway.
Using `terra` instead is not an option as this is for my thesis where I research differences in regridding algorithms across various libraries, so in this case using `raster` is the very point ;)

Comment: Yes, it overwrites previous settings.  But you could use terra to *plot* Raster* objects `plot(rast(x))`  --- I suppose you would actually want to plot everything with the same method?